# Can we view PostgreSQL tables in django admin or in rails admin, I saw one day my QA colleague viewing tables from rails admin, was that SQL tables?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, django-rest-framework, django-admin, rails-admin

Just a question,
I am Front-end Developer, newbie Backend
I saw one day my QA colleague viewing tables from rails admin which was deployed for Backend Testing.
So was that MySQL tables, can't we do the same with PostgreSQL with Django admin and rails admin?
Is it recommended (every one is doing) ?
or we need to do some hi-tech configurations? just to achieve this, maybe that is meaningless.

I am just configuring Django-rest-framework

Comment: Instead of asking here why don't you ask your colleague. It is impossible for us to know what they were looking at. Also, define your terms. F/E? B/E?, DRF (Daily Racing Form)?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I had updated the question.

Comment: In a sense, yes, rails-admin by default will build a CRUD for each model backed by a table in your application.

Comment: Thanks! Also just completed the setup for postgresql + Django-rest-framework,  now i can manage my tables from django-admin after registering the models in admin.py file